# Ambiguous Auto Layout Constraints (Programmatically added)

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I don't know why my programmatically created constraints are ambiguous, I even try to init from a Nib with the same constraints, it works but why my code are not.

```
@interface rootViewController: UIViewController
@end

@implementation rootViewController

- (void)loadView
{
self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];

    UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:theView];

    NSArray *arr = @[
    [theView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor],

    [theView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor],

    [theView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor],

    [theView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor]];

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:arr];

}

@end

//And I load it in the ApplicationDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[rootViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

It is really interesting that you cannot find problem while debugging.

[The debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0glPJ.png)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for Yun CHEN's help, he told me a lot, but the real problem is that.

**There are some thing different between the view created programatically and from Interface Builder.**

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints;
//the property of UIView
```

Iet's read the discription:

By default, **the property is set to YES for any view you programmatically create**. If you add views in Interface Builder, the system automatically sets this property to NO.

So that is, just set this hidden boss to NO. everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is ambiguous for calculating width.It cannot be calculated by `Leading` and `CenterX` constraint. (Height is well calculated by top and bottom constraints). So:

Case 1, if the view's **width equal to its super view's**, the `CenterX` constraint should be removed, and add the `Trailing` constraint.

Case 2, if the view's **width is a certain value and the view is centered**, the `Leading` constraint should be removed, and add the `Width` constraint.

Case 3, if the view's **width is a certain value and the view is left aligned**, the `CenterX` constraint should be removed, and add the `Width` constraint.

Comment: Why there is ambiguous for calculating width, I think the combination of CenterX and Leading works fine in the Nib file, could you tell some detail please:>

Comment: So what's the width expected?

Comment: En, I tried two cases, and Xcode still tells me there is ambigous result.

Comment: It is expected to share the same width as the superView.

Comment: So use the Case 1 solution.  Why?  Just think how could Xcode know where the view's right side is?

Comment: When centered in X axis and determined the leading_side of the view, the trailing side will share the same width from the center. En, it is a sample code from the auto layout document, after trying your solution, I think the problem is not here, maybe the way to add the constraints.

Comment: I don't agree with above opinion. Evidence: The Storyboard will give you a red warning if you add only: Top, bottom, leading, centerX constraints to a view. You could try it by yourself. If it's being used too much, maybe there are many ambiguous warnings ignored. It's better to check them.

Comment: According to the debug info, the Ambiguous is between Top, CenterY, Bottom. Looks it's not here, just find where you applied CenterY with Top and Bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I just tried a stupid way, align left to left, right to right, top to top, and bottom to bottom, en, it is not working, so I just commit above.

Comment: I FOUND the answer, wait some time.